# How to change a column/Field of asp grid to readonly in code behind (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a asp grid on front, its all columns are enabled.
On specific action, I want only one column to be read only. How can i do this code behind file (vb.net).

Update :
I want to disable all rows of one column. Not only the selected one.

Thanks..

Comment: Just Create EventHandler for Specific Action and than in event you can get data of perticular column of current row.

Comment: Well i want to disable all rows of a column

Comment: You mean to say you want to disable a column. Right?

Comment: Yes, from code behind in vb.net

Comment: grd.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Enabled = False

Comment: You are 6 second faster than me-@eirishainjel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
For row As Integer = 0 To grd.Rows.Count - 1
grd.Rows(row).Cells(1).Enabled = False
Next
```

Comment: Simple but effective :D